# Is it possible to use raw socket on iphone simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, raw-sockets

I would like to develop an app for jailbroken iphone that uses raw sockets. 
Is it possible to run it on iphone simulator or do I need necessarily a jailbroken device?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't run raw sockets on iPhone simulator since simulator has same OS architecture as iOS device. You may try jail breaking the simulator itself, but I think it will be a tough task. [This link](http://sharedinstance.net/2013/10/running-tweaks-in-simulator/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it, and many projects do that.  However, please note that it would not work on device, so you should only use this for testing purposes in the simulator.